# date with tabs space in between in unix

Tags: unix, terminal

What is the command for printing the year, month, and date with a horizontal tab between the fields in **unix**? is the followin answer correct??

%date +"%y  %m  %d"

i know tat $ date +"%y-%m-%d" will give 88-05-21

Comment: Curious, if you already have a possible answer why are you asking if it works instead of just trying it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the bash shell:

```
$ date +"%y"$'\t'"%m"$'\t'"%d"
10  12  15
```

Note the `$'\t'` shell notation which produces a literal horizontal tab character.

EDIT:

Many commands, such as `printf(1)` support some kind of notation to specify any special characters like a horizontal tab:

```
$ printf 'x\ty\n'
x   y
```

If the command does not support something like this, the way to deal with it is to embed a literal horizontal tab in the format string. Unfortunately the shell tends to treat the tab key specially e.g. to perform auto-completion.

In bash (and perhaps other sh-like shells) there is a convenient notation like `$'\t'` to get around this issue.

Another way is to invoke the "quote mode" of the shell. In many shells (including bash and tcsh) this can be done by pressing Ctrl-V before pressing the special character. This will enable the shell's quote mode for the next character only:

```
$ echo 'x    q'
x   q
```

The result above can be achieved by pressing Ctrl-V after the x and before pressing the tab key.

Comment: @user238284: Please tell us which OS and which shell you are working on - otherwise we cannot really answer.

Answer (score 2):

To print the date with spaces in between all you need to do is: `date "+%y %m %d"`.  I highly recommend you check out the man page (`man date`) for `date`.

Comment: Please note that the OP wants to have horizontal tabs as separators, not spaces.

Comment: Oops, my bad! For some reason between reading the question and writing the answer that bit slipped my mind.